# Javascript validation doesn't work because of documents.getElementsById()

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm having trouble with this code,if I add the line I have commented out, the form seems to go to the page I've linked in action without undergoing validation.But if i don't include it, the validation works fine and the alert box displays the message.I don't understand the reason why it doesn't work.

```
 function validateform(){   
      var flag=0;
      var uname=document.forms["f1"]["uname"].value;
      var pass=document.forms["f1"]["pass"].value;
      var fname=document.forms["f1"]["fname"].value;
      var lname=document.forms["f1"]["lname"].value;
      var phone=document.forms["f1"]["phone"].value;
      var email=document.forms["f1"]["email"].value;
      var err="";
      if(uname==""||uname==null) {
           err+="Username cannot be left blank\n";
           //document.getElementsById("uname").style.backgroundColor="red";
           flag=1;
      }
      if(pass==""||pass==null){
           err+="Password cannot be left blank\n";
           flag=1;
      }
      if(email==""||email==null){
           err+="Email cannot be left blank\n";
           flag=1;
      }    
      if(flag==0){
           return true;
      }else{
           alert(err);
           return false;
      }     
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? If there's no element with that id value, that line will throw an exception and the function will be aborted. The `<input>` element named "uname" needs **both** a "name" and "id" attribute with that value.

Comment: turns out i shouldn't have used the plural since the id is unique, thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

You've made a typo.

It is `document.getElementById('id')` and not `document.getElementsById`

It gets a single element as ids are unique and meant for a single element.

It is also named `getElementById` due to the fact that there can't be duplicate ids.

Comment: quick question I would be right if I used getElementsByName wouldn't I (since the name is not unique)? but that gives me the same error as above.

Comment: getElementsByName gives you a node list.

Comment: You can try this: `document.getElementsByName('namehere')[0]`

Comment: yeah this worked, I thought i could get away without specifying the [0] since i have only one field with that name but i was wrong.

Comment: success story of a programming newbie http://gyazo.com/656fd460c8a62143d76025910bec1b6a

Comment: @user3204064, what is that link?

Comment: @user3204064, you should mark the answer by clicking on the tick

Answer (score 2):

An id is a *unique* identifier. There can be only one element of a given id. Therefore the method to get elements by their id is not plural. `getElementById`, not `getElementsById`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `getElementsByName` and 2. `getElementById`.

   1. because multiple HTML elements with same name are allowed
   2. because `ID` is unique and cannot be assigned to multiple HTML Elements.

thats why: `getElementsById` and `getElementByName` are wrong

Comment: I used getElementsByName() but that also causes the validation to be skipped. It seems that only the getelementbyid works.

Comment: @user3204064 ``getElementsByName`` returns Node List btw. you should change your check accordingly

Answer (score 0):

please try this correct the function name document.getElementById its not elements
    document.getElementById("uname").style.bacgroundColor="red";

Answer (score 0):

I think you want getElementById not getElementsById  (not the S in elementS).  Depending on the browser you are using and what you have turned on getElementsById will fail gracefully and never let you know about it or it will display an error.